# Is there a gradle plugin to package Java Webstart applications?

Tags: java, build, gradle, maven-plugin, java-web-start

Is there a gradle plugin to package Java Webstart (JWS) applications, similar to what [Maven webstart plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/webstart/webstart-maven-plugin/) does? I need to automate at least the following tasks:

- jnlp descriptor generation based on an existing template, automatic adding project dependencies;
- jar signing based on the files described on jnlp file or project dependencies;

Answer (score 1):

As of Aug 2016, the answer is "no".

There is a plugin under development per @Jake's answer. But there is no turn key solution. You'll have to do the work yourself to create a webstart app in Gradle... either with your own custom solution or by contributing to the plugin mentioned until it works for you.

Here's the plugin direct link: https://github.com/tschulte/gradle-jnlp-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Found the following [link](http://www.apprenticeshipnotes.org/2013/01/generating-webstart-files-using-gradle.html) outside of Stack Overflow and looks like it does some of what you are looking for but not all. Hopefully this gets you closer to what you need...

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but answering anyway.
I could configure [gradle-jnlp-plugin](https://github.com/tschulte/gradle-jnlp-plugin).
Steps:
-Create an empty folder.
-Create src folder with Java code. I used the sample [AccessibleScrollDemo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/misc/index.html).
-Copy keystore.ks from [examples](https://github.com/tschulte/gradle-jnlp-plugin/tree/develop/examples) or create your own using genkey task in plug-in.
-Create build.gradle with following configuration.
The plug-in has [examples](https://github.com/tschulte/gradle-jnlp-plugin/tree/develop/examples) of various options for jnlp task.
-Run plug-in task using gradle (v2.4 or more).

```
gradle createWebstartDir
```

-This will create the jnlp file under build directory, and also jars in build/lib.

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'de.gliderpilot.gradle.jnlp:gradle-jnlp-plugin:+'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'idea'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'de.gliderpilot.jnlp'

group = 'misc'

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
targetCompatibility = 1.6

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

mainClassName = 'misc.AccessibleScrollDemo'

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDir "src"
}

dependencies {

    runtime('log4j:log4j:1.2.17') {
        exclude group: 'ant',         module: 'ant-nodeps'
        exclude group: 'ant',         module: 'ant-junit'
        exclude group: 'ant-contrib', module: 'ant-contrib'
    }
    runtime 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.21'

    testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4'
}

jnlp {
    useVersions = false
    usePack200 = false

    withXml {
        information {
            title project.name
            vendor project.group ?: project.name
        }
        security {
            'all-permissions'()
        }
    }
    signJarParams = [keystore: 'keystore.ks', alias: 'myalias', storepass: 'mystorepass']
}

compileGroovy.enabled = false

afterEvaluate {
    // prevent ClassCastException
    project.version = project.version.toString()
}

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the [Gradle JNLP Plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/de.gliderpilot.jnlp) currently registered in the [Gradle Plugins directory](https://plugins.gradle.org/) may be the project for which you're looking.

Tobias Schulte's Gradle JNLP Plugin ( tschulte/gradle-jnlp-plugin on GitHub ) was striving for this about a year ago, but the new plugin is both registered in the Gradle Plugin site and looks to be under much more active development.

Comment: The Gradle JNLP Plugin does not work. Following the instructions on their github page does not yield a working webstart application. I'm sure they are working hard on this plugin, but as of Aug 2016 I cannot recommend the plugin for someone not ready to dive into the source code and make contributions to improve the plugin.

Comment: Also, the registered plugin you mention and Tobias Schulte's plugin are the same. There are not two plugins.